# Special subset symbol

Tags: math-mode, symbols, amsmath, relation-symbols

The symbol `\Subset` provides a subset symbol which "repeats itself twice," essentially. Is there anyway to produce the same symbol which "repeats itself thrice" (i.e., take two lines in between the standard `\subset` symbol)?

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. There is no such symbol in any package I know. You could design one using TikZ or by scaling and combining other symbols, but they would look inconsistent compared to the existing `\subset` symbol. There really isn't enough room inside `\Subset` to fit a third and have it look good. What would the meaning of such a symbol be?

Comment: @SandyG Thank you for the response. It is for a certain type of inclusion relation that extends on the other two (generalizing ```\subset``` and ```\Subset```). Even if the relation is much larger than the other two, is it possible to give an example?

Comment: @SandyG The third line can be very small, like the size of the letter c.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a make-your-own solution with TikZ. The sizing is not great, but I'm not sure how to make it more consistent with the ordinary `\subset` symbol.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\SSubset}{\mathrel{\tikz[yscale=.2, xscale=.22]{
  \draw[line cap=round](1,1)--(.5,1) arc(90:270:.5) -- (1,0)
    (1,.8)--(.5,.8) arc(90:270:.3) -- (1,.2)
    (1,.6)--(.5,.6) arc(90:270:.1) -- (1,.4);
}}}

\begin{document}

$A\SSubset B\Subset C\subset D$

\end{document}
```